# How to upload file by help of path name using Django and Python?

Tags: python, django, file

I need to upload file into some folder inside the project using the path instead of browse from folder using Django and Python. Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'upload' %}">
   <input name="name" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

Suppose here user paste one file path name `e.g-/home/subrajyoti/Pictures/abc.pdf,.png etc` and click on upload button in this case I need to remove the original file name with one time stamp and save this file into project folder and path into db.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think browsers allow you to access file system with a path.
The only way browsers allow you to access file system is by "Choose a file" from browser.

This is for security reasons to protect users.